# Assembly: incorrect behaviour when reading file

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I am trying to open a file and print its content on screen. I was able to do so but I discovered strange behavior when using offset.

I have the following variables in data segment:

```
filename1 db 'filename.txt$'
filename2 db 0, 0, 'filename.txt$'
fhandler dw ?
```

In the following code segment if I replace 'FILE' with 'offset filename1' it works as intended and prints out buffer filled with specified file content. However if I replace 'FILE' with 'offset filename2+2' buffer is filled with command line input instead of file content. I presume that the file opening has failed in this example.

```
; load data
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

; open file
mov ah, 3dH
mov al, 0
mov dx, FILE ; replace this
int 21h
mov fhandler, ax

; read file
mov ah, 3fh
mov bx, fhandler
mov cx, buffer_size
mov dx, offset buffer
int 21h

; print buffer
mov ah, 9
mov dx, offset buffer
int 21h

; close file
mov ah, 3eh
mov bx, fhandler
int 21h
```

Printing filename2 like this works correctly:

```
mov ah, 9
mov dx, offset filename2+2
int 21h
```

I can work around it and use the first variant in my code but I don't understand why the second example doesn't work as I intended.

Comment: Set a breakpoint below `mov dx, FILE ` and inspect the memory pointed to by `ds:dx` in debugger.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that file names have to be ended with 0 rather than '$'. I had to define variable filename2 like this:

```
db filename2 0, 0, 'filename.txt$', 0
```

With this definition I can print my variable with system function 9 (output character string) for debugging purposes and also use it for opening files with system function 3fh.